# Disable 'ESC' and 'Shift + Tab' history shortcuts in terminal

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys, bash-history

When in a bash terminal, if I hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> the command line goes to the history where I can move around to previous bash commands with vi-like bindings. I get messed up when in this mode since I will unintentionally run various commands. I can only get out of this by hitting `a` or `i`.

I hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> frequently (though, accidentally) in my normal usage and I would like to disable this history search mode altogether.

Edit: The event also occurs when I hit any of F1 through F12 (except F4 and F11), pause/break, delete, home, pgup, and pgdn. I'm beginning to think it's related to unbound keys or perhaps something weird with my keyboard.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. If I hit `Esc`, nothing happens and if I hit `Shift`+`Tab` nothing happens as well. In order to browse my command history I have to hit `Ctrl`+`R`. All these with gnome-terminal. What terminal are you using?

Comment: When I do "echo $TERM" it returns "xterm". I figure that's how to tell which terminal I'm using.

Comment: What system are you using? Ubuntu, KUbuntu, XUbuntu... ?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I'm not sure what `echo $TERM` does, but it returns `xterm` for me, even though I'm using terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going into some "vi-mode" in the terminal because of a line in my .bashrc file: `set -o vi`. Removing this line solved my problem.